# MvcContrib.UI.Grid pagination problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib

I have an object which contains quite a few other objects in an IList called possible values. I have successfully used the mvccontrib grid plus paging before but would like to add the grid to the object’s page – hope you know what I mean. So I did something like this in my controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ViewResult Bla(string Id, int? page)

ViewData["PossibleValues"] = XYZ.PossibleValues.AsPagination(page ?? 1, 10);
```

PossibleValues definitely contains data but not ViewData["PossibleValues"]. Is this because AsPagination relies on lazy loading or something? Thanks.

Chris

Comment: `would like to add the grid to the object’s page – hope you know what I mean` - Umm, not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: The object has a bunch of objects. i would like to show the object's details and its objects as grid in one page. I just tried ViewData["PossibleValues"] = XYZ.PossibleValues.ToList().AsQueryable().AsPagination(page ?? 1, 10) still no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out. Use in the controller:

```
ViewData["PossibleValues"] = XYZ.PossibleValues.ToList().AsQueryable().AsPagination(page ?? 1, 10);
```

Then in the view:

```
<%= Html.Grid(ViewData["PossibleValues"] as IEnumerable<FFFF>).Columns(column =>
                           {
                            column.For(gf => gf.Value).Named("Value");
                        }).Empty("Sorry no data.")%>
                       <%= Html.Pager((IPagination)(ViewData["PossibleValues"] as IEnumerable<FFFF>))%>
```