# MVC contrib pager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, mvccontrib

I am using it like this:

```
<%= Html.Pager((IPagination)Model) %>
```

Is there are simple way to change the rendered url. I had a look for more documentation but couldn't find much.

Comment: My problem is that I have a grid in an Index view for a controller and the action bit is swallowed off. It work fine for other views but not for Index views. So I thought I can force the creation of the action bit to generate the correct url.

Comment: I tried <%= Html.Pager((IPagination)Model)
            .Link(currentPage => Url.Action("Index", new {  
            page = currentPage
            }))
            %> but the Index bit is swalloed. If I use "Bla" instead of "Index" the URL is generated. Why is this? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What exactly do you want to change?

This is how I change the URL:

```
 Html.Pager(Model.AssetsPagedList)
        .First("First")
        .Last("Last")
        .Next("Next")
        .Previous("Previous")
          .Link(currentPage => Url.Action("Browse", new {  
            page = currentPage,
            searchTerm = Model.SearchModel.SearchTerm,
            excludedWords = Model.SearchModel.ExcludedWords,
            minPrice = Model.SearchModel.MinPrice,
            maxPrice = Model.SearchModel.MaxPrice,
            locationId = Model.SearchModel.LocationId,  
            catalogId = Model.SearchModel.CatalogId
        }))
```

You could also create a helper something like this:

```
public static Pager Pager(this HtmlHelper helper, IPagination model, FormCollection formCollection)
    {
      // here you can use MvcContrib.UI.Pager.PaginationExtensions.Pager static methods
      // or create MvcContrib.Pagination.Pager class directly
    }
```

Comment: I tried <%= Html.Pager((IPagination)Model) .Link(currentPage => Url.Action("Index", new { page = currentPage })) %> but the Index bit is swalloed. If I use "Bla" instead of "Index" the URL is generated. Why is this? Thanks.

Comment: No idea. You can download the source, build it and use the debugger if you want to figure it out. The code is not complicated.

Comment: For me this does not work, because now the page is the same for next (page = 1) and previous (page = 1). You need to distinguish betweem them in the Link delegate but you can't. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what do you want to change.

In the following sample I am changing the pagination links to use ajax

```
$("#addressListPlaceholder .paginationRight a").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        dataType: "html",
        url: this.href,
        data: {},
        success: function (response) {
            $("#addressListPlaceholder").html('').html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in anything that is castable to IPagination.  For example, see this SO question/answer: [MvcContrib.UI.Grid pagination problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227707/mvccontrib-ui-grid-pagination-problem)

You can also modify the pager after generation time using jQuery.  See this post for an example:  http://thekindofme.wordpress.com/2009/01/12/ajax-enabling-mvccontrib-grid-pagination-with-jquery/